# Converting array of Strings to array of doubles

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, for-loop

I have an array of strings. The user (hopefully) will fill it with {"word", "word", ...} and then some number of doubles/values after that. I need to take all those values after the first two words, parse them to doubles, and add them to a double array. For example, if the String array is {"add", "key", "2", "4", "5", "1"}, my new double array would return {1, 2, 4, 5, 1}. Here's a code snippet, let me know what you can make of it. For reference, getOption() is the method that returns the array of Strings. Thanks!

```
public double[] getValues(){
    double values[] = new double[getOption().length - 2]; //first two values cannot be parsed to double
    for (int i = 2; i < getOption().length; i++){
        double valueDouble;
        valueDouble = Double.parseDouble(getOption()[i].trim());
        values[i] = valueDouble;
    }
    return values;
}
```

I'm attempting to use the for loop to pull one value (getOption()[i]), parse it to a double, add it to the values array, and restart the loop until the end of the String array (getOption()) is reached.

edit: forgot to mention my issue: it returns nothing and throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException 1 in a few seconds.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: added an edit: it throws an arrayoutofboundsexception 1

Comment: `values[i] = valueDouble;` should be `values[i-2] = valueDouble;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that:

```
values[i] = valueDouble;
```

Should be:

```
values[i - 2] = valueDouble;
```

As you've offset `options` by 2, but `values` does not reflect that.

Also, you should really consider storing the result of `getOptions()`. That might be why you're having an issue of it returning nothing since each one could be different. This would be the case where `getOptions()` requires user input or could change between calls. It is also just quicker and clearer.

```
String[] options = getOptions();
double values[] = new double[options.length - 2]; 
// ...
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I added the values[i - 2] bit (great suggestion!) and created String[] options as you suggested. Still, when I call my switch case in my controller method that summons getValues() I get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 still. It marks the line that calls getValues() as the issue.

Comment: @Qdhcjv `It marks the line that calls getValues() as the issue.` Is that line calling the method like `getValues()[1]`, or is the line inside the `getValues()` method?

Comment: It's calling getValues() in a HashMap put statement. (dataMap.put(keyString, getValues())). keyString is the key for the input, getValues() is the array of values for that key.

Comment: @Qdhcjv testing the [corrected code appears to work fine](http://ideone.com/6sHWBd). The issue is probably coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Huh... I'll keep digging through my code. Thank you!

Comment: I still can't figure it out. Want to help? My case calls System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getValues())); to ensure it's working and it prints nothing. If I force the option array in getValues to a certain value rather than calling getOption, it works, but it doesn't work with values given with getOption. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: @Qdhcjv try debugging and seeing what `getOption()` is returning. To me it seems like it isn't returning what you expect it to be.

Comment: Seems normal... entering add dsn 2 4 5 to my switch statement returns [add, dsn, 2, 4, 5] like normal. Unless the [] mean something different from {}?

Comment: weird, I added a debug case for my switch statement and it does return the values [1, 2, 3, 4] if I enter the string "debug key 1 2 3 4" twice.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should never say "The user wont do that", because you cant be sure of that.

Second, your `values` array is starting on index 2 and it only has 4 positions. When you're assigning it values you should substract 2 from it: `values[i - 2] = valueDouble;`

Comment: Thanks for the tip!! I know I can't trust the users to enter it properly- but for the sake of our assignment (this is high school level :/), we can expect it and throwing an error when the user does it wrong is okay.

Comment: If you know how to handle the exception then you'll be alright. Hope you've solved the issue.

Comment: I am using values[i - 2], I still see the error. 99% sure it's related to my getValues() call, so the issue is still present. Working on it though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `values[i-2]`. It think it will solve the problem ;)